# Asynchronous ajax call blocking UI

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

Once the JSP is rendered, I'm here trying to make an *Asynchronous* call via ajax to load additional information on the page.

I'm expecting that ajax load to happen gracefully without hampering the UI scroll bar navigation. But the call blocks the UI until the onLoad is complete.

At other times, this service blocks UI even on a mouse click ajax call (the cursor remains as `pointer` type until data is loaded).

In both cases, I'm building DOM via javascript (like creating innerHTMl for a div or table). Is it because of this? or something else? I'm attaching my ajax request code.

Appreciate your help. (Sorry, I tried to format the code, but I'm unable to get it right here)

```
function requestService(theService, theParamObj, isSyncCall) {
    var ajaxRequest = getAjaxRequest();  
    var params = "data="; 
    if(theParamObj != null)
        params += encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(theParamObj));

    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 1) {
            showLoadingBox();
        }
        if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {          
            handleResponse(ajaxRequest.responseText, theService, theParamObj);
            hideLoadingBox();
        }
    };

    var queryString = "?timestamp=" + new Date().getMilliseconds() + "&theService=" + theService;
    if(isSyncCall == null)
        isSyncCall = false;
    ajaxRequest.open("POST", g_Service + queryString, isSyncCall);
    ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajaxRequest.send(params);
}
```

**Update**: 
onLoad call to this service

```
function loadAdInfo(){
   var theParamObj = {"REQUEST_URI" : window.location.href};
   requestService('getAdInfo', theParamObj, false);
}
```

Comment: code for getAjaxRequest(). Why don't you use jquery?

Comment: Remove the call to `handleResponse` and see what happens.

Comment: @giammin, it might take some more time for the project to start using jQuery...may not be now.

Comment: @Jon, I can try that, but that's where I handle the DOM building. Should there be a work around?

Comment: @Harsh..: I know that's where you build the DOM. My point is that if your DOM building takes forever, obviously the page will become unresponsive until you are done and it will not be the fault of the AJAX part.

Comment: @Harsh..: On the other hand, it seems I was wrong to assume that the code was not inherently problematic. As odedsh answers below, you are explicitly making a synchronous call.

Comment: @Jon, I've noticed the problem with code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XMLHTTPObject open method is defined like this:

```
open(method,url,async)  Specifies the type of request, the URL, and if the request should be handled asynchronously or not.

method: the type of request: GET or POST
url: the location of the file on the server
async: true (asynchronous) or false (synchronous)
```

You are passing false. so you are calling it synch